# Choosing SQL Data Type for DateTime-data (compatible w. MySQL & MSSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to save `DateTime` data in a database and need advices to choose the right SQL Data Type.

I want to save a `Start-DateTime` and `End-DateTime`.
Subsequently I want to output the `Start-DateTime` directly in a table and I want to output the duration taken between Start and End. So that you can imagine it better, the result should look like this:

[image: Screenshot Output-Table]

- Saving `Y-m-d H:i:s` is too less. I also want milliseconds (1 decimal place).
- My PHP application supports **MySQL** and **Microsoft SQL-Server** as target-database. The datatype should be easily compatible with both.

Which SQL Data Type should I choose for the columns `Start-DateTime` and `End-DateTime`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't expect SQL to be transferable between RDBMS, if you're working with 2 different ones you're going to need code that is different. As for what to store date and time data in, well and date and time data type e. Look at the documentation bfoe the RDBMS you are *actually* using and it'll tell you your options.

Comment: *Saving Y-m-d H:i:s is too less. I also want milliseconds (1 decimal place).* `DATETIME(1)` for MySQL and `DATETIME2(1)` for SQL Server. *The datatype should be easily compatible with both.* There is no such datatype. The only possibility is a timestamp normalized to ms and stored in BIGINT datatype, but it needs convertion specific for each DBMS again.

Comment: 1 decimal place isn't milliseconds. Though the term is rarely heard, it's deciseconds

Comment: @Akina Using `DATETIME(3)` in MySQL and `DATETIME2(3)` in MsSQL is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime2(7) for MsSQL. i use always datetime2(7) with php,c# etc.. cause right calculate of difference between dates miliseconds. its look like '2021-02-20 15:35:43.5866667'.